# Post html content to an activity with Google + Domains API

Tags: google-plus

I'm triying to post HTML content to an activity with the new google + domains API with no success.

```
Activity activity = new Activity()
        .setObject(new Activity.PlusObject().setContent("First line<br><b>second line</b>"))
        .setAccess(acl);
```

Acording to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/plus/v1domains/java/latest/) with setConent you can specify "The HTML-formatted content, which is suitable for display." but when i try to post some html its get displayed as plain text.

I need to create an activity with some linebreaks and bold text. How can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the content (HTML) field is only meant for output, you are not allowed to write in HTML. You should be writing in plain text (as you do in the browser), newlines are respected with normal line breaks (`\n`)

This field is useful to display formatted posts that contain links etc..